# Table numbers in tabularx are overlapped, solution?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to build a table with multiple panels, for instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}% raggedleft column X
\begin{document}

   \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics and Correlations for Variables}
    \label{tbl:stats-and-correlations}


    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{9}{Y}}
        \toprule
            \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Panel A}} \\

    Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{S.D.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Median} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    net profit & 595 & 309,923.500 & 1,235,088.000 & 15 & 20,324.5 & 64,431 & 226,601.5 & 17,095,868 \\ 
    total assets & 623 & 37,255,614.000 & 140,879,480.000 & 42,077 & 1,560,427 & 4,326,558 & 16,847,227 & 1,803,048,120 \\ 
    RoA & 595 & 0.017 & 0.014 & 0.0001 & 0.008 & 0.014 & 0.022 & 0.108 \\ 
    number of board members & 544 & - & - & 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 & 39 \\ 
    total staff number  & 542 & - & - & 5 & 26 & 50 & 160 & 3,505 \\ 
    no of branch covered cities & 551 & - & - & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 156 \\ 
    establish year & 493 & - & - & 1,907 & 1,919 & 1,925 & 1,930 & 1,934 \\ 
    bank age & 493 & - & - & 1 & 4 & 8 & 15 & 29 \\  
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{7}{Y}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Correlations}} \\
        \midrule
        & Var.\ 1 & Var.\ 2 & Var.\ 3 & Var.\ 4 & Var.\ 5 & Var.\ 6 & Var.\ 7 \\
        Variable~1 &    0.78 &    0.37 &    0.48 &    0.10 &    0.13 &    0.58 &    0.41 \\
        Variable~2 &    0.46 &    0.86 &    0.96 &    0.44 &    0.15 &    0.56 &    0.31 \\
        Variable~3 &    0.03 &    0.75 &    0.11 &    0.44 &    0.71 &    0.06 &    0.26 \\
        Variable~4 &    0.21 &    0.25 &    0.38 &    0.88 &    0.24 &    0.52 &    0.46 \\
        Variable~5 &    0.20 &    0.93 &    0.54 &    0.96 &    0.55 &    0.82 &    0.62 \\
        Variable~6 &    0.67 &    0.85 &    0.74 &    0.99 &    0.27 &    0.48 &    0.85 \\
        Variable~7 &    0.82 &    0.89 &    0.68 &    0.06 &    0.02 &    0.30 &    0.10 \\
        \bottomrule


    \end{tabularx}

   {\footnotesize   [1]\ Footnote 1: Variable~1 is calculated as\ldots \endgraf
    [2]\ Correlations are Pearson. vxccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccCCCdasdasjkdkjasdkadsdsajdnsjakdjlkasld}
   \end{table}

      \end{document}
```

the result:

[image]

Any idea about the overlapping?

Comment: The solution here is to make the columns of a different specification, like `r`, not `Y` (for those where the overlapping occur).

Comment: @Werner - See my answer for an implementation of your recommendation. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upper table has two issues:

- The numbers in the first two rows are of entirely different magnitudes from those in the remaining rows.
- Even if you rescale the numbers -- below, I suggest factors of 10^3 and 10^6 -- the table still won't fit because the data rows are all made to occupy the same widths. Given the overall space limit, this results in more than enough space for some columns but not enough space for others.

The remedy is to (a) rescale the numbers in the first two data rows and (b) use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabularx` environment. (A chief reason for using `tabularx` is when you need to let overly long lines wrap automatically. This is not the case here. Actually, it would be a really bad idea to let long numbers wrap automatically!) The overall width will still be `\linewidth`, but the fitting is achieved by letting the column widths vary as needed. For symmetry, I suggest you use a `tabular*` environment for the lower table as well.

Incidentally, I don't think one should use commas as thousands-separators for four-digit year numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out optimal widths
\caption{Descriptive Statistics and Correlations for Variables}
\label{tbl:stats-and-correlations}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c*{7}{r}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Descriptive Statistics}} \\

& N & \mc{Mean} & \mc{S.D.} & \mc{Min} & \mc{Pctl(25)} & \mc{Median} & \mc{Pctl(75)} & \mc{Max} \\ 
\midrule
net profit ($\times10^3$)& 595 & 309.92 & 1,235.09 & 0.0015 & 20.32 & 64.43 & 226.60 & 17,095.87 \\ 
total assets ($\times10^6$) & 623 & 37,255.6 & 140,879.5 & 0.042 & 1,560.4 & 4,326.6 & 16,847.2 & 1,803,048.1 \\ 
    RoA & 595 & 0.017 & 0.014 & 0.0001 & 0.008 & 0.014 & 0.022 & 0.108 \\ 
    number of board members & 544 & - & - & 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 & 39 \\ 
    total staff number  & 542 & - & - & 5 & 26 & 50 & 160 & 3,505 \\ 
    no of branch covered cities & 551 & - & - & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 156 \\ 
    establish year & 493 & - & - & 1907 & 1919 & 1925 & 1930 & 1934 \\ 
    bank age & 493 & - & - & 1 & 4 & 8 & 15 & 29 \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{7}{r}}
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Correlations}} \\
\midrule
& Var.\ 1 & Var.\ 2 & Var.\ 3 & Var.\ 4 & Var.\ 5 & Var.\ 6 & Var.\ 7 \\
Variable~1 &    0.78 &    0.37 &    0.48 &    0.10 &    0.13 &    0.58 &    0.41 \\
Variable~2 &    0.46 &    0.86 &    0.96 &    0.44 &    0.15 &    0.56 &    0.31 \\
Variable~3 &    0.03 &    0.75 &    0.11 &    0.44 &    0.71 &    0.06 &    0.26 \\
Variable~4 &    0.21 &    0.25 &    0.38 &    0.88 &    0.24 &    0.52 &    0.46 \\
Variable~5 &    0.20 &    0.93 &    0.54 &    0.96 &    0.55 &    0.82 &    0.62 \\
Variable~6 &    0.67 &    0.85 &    0.74 &    0.99 &    0.27 &    0.48 &    0.85 \\
Variable~7 &    0.82 &    0.89 &    0.68 &    0.06 &    0.02 &    0.30 &    0.10 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabular*}
\footnotesize   
[1]\ Footnote 1: Variable~1 is calculated as\ldots \endgraf
    [2]\ Correlations are Pearson. vxccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccCCCdasdasjkdkjasdkadsdsajdnsjakdjlkasld
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the inspiring answer. Particularly the rescale part of the first two rows which I never thought about.

Comment: Effective solution, undeniably! Nevertheless, I remember a recommendation in a guide for writing a paper (in engineering context) about the rescaling of numbers: it is recommended to use unit prefixes instead of writing x10^n, since the latter method can rise doubts like "are this numbers TO BE multiplied or ALREADY multiplied by this factor?". Obviously the solution of using prefixes is not viable in this case, but i think that the consideration can be of interest, since without reading the numbers in the first attempt table, I would be in doubt about them, exactly in the way I explained.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis - Thanks! Writing `(in thousands)` and `(in millions)` instead of `($\times10^3$)` and `($\times10^6$)` might, at the margin, reduce some ambiguity regarding the scaling. Actually, if this were *my* table, I'd almost certainly re-organize the way the material is presented, so as not to have to show assets (in billions of currency units), bank age (less than 100, in years), and Return on Assets (a fractional term between 0 and 1) in such close proximity.

Comment: +1 for not using `tabularx` for data tables:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can you give me some reference for this argument? Just in the case I'll be tempted to use tabularx for data. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis - I'll offer my own argument against `tabularx`. (Let's see if David disagrees...) A principal reason for using `tabularx` is to let LaTeX perform automatic line wrapping on material that is (in some sense or other) "too wide" in one or more columns. For the table at hand, though, line wrapping would be catastrophic. Since line wrapping is out of the question, it's better to use a `tabular*` environment if the objective is still to make the table to take up the full width of the textblock. That, or just a plain, centered `tabular` environment...

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis not sure what reference you need, I wrote tabularx and I'd never use it for such a table:-) `tabularx` is _all_ about adjusting the final table width by altering the _line breaking_ within columns of text. In a numeric table where there is no line breaking in the cells `tabularx` can only do harm, `tabular*` is better, and usually `tabular` is better still (stretching the table to full width just makes it harder to read) not so bad here as it is almost full width anyway so it just removes the margins but for smaller tables it does not improve the table

Comment: @Mico groupthink wins the day :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - :-) I was once in charge of editing a conference proceedings volume (using LaTeX, of course!), and I had an amazing experience working closely with a gifted and friendly book designer on all book layout matters. (The organization I worked for back then had an excellent publications department.) Almost all papers had lots of tables, and the designer felt that the book would look better if (almost) all tables had the same overall width. I ended up using `tabular*` (with width set to `\textwidth`) for most tables. The result was indeed a nice, "uniform" look.

Comment: @Mico book designers are certainly allowed to break any latex style guidelines/rules. But whenever I see  two-column tables with **a** in the left column, three quarters of a page width of white space, then **2** somewhere on the right, and the same repeated on each line, I feel sad for having written `tabularx` and inflicted such things on the reader:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Indeed, that's gross abuse of `tabularx` -- as well as serious mistreatment of readers. Not to worry -- the conference proceedings volume I edited did not feature any such tables! (Aside: Did `tabularx` even exist in 1995/96? I don't think I was even aware of `tabularx` back then.) Anyway, much of my editing time was spent on trying to figure out how to reduce the widths of various tables so that they would fit inside the margins, not on how to make them wider...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46063/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-mico).

Comment: @Mico You are right. I don't want put them together on a table either. But due to the limited space of journal, I have to. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.